# How to filter a serializer manytomany field in djangorestframework

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework, django-queryset, django-serializer

I want to filter the `manytomany` field based on the current instance selected field['customer']. I want the `cart_items` manytomany field to only contain the cart_items of the selected customer in cart API.

**models.py**

```
class Product(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product_id = ShortUUIDField(unique=True, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    # price = MoneyField(max_digits=14, decimal_places=2)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=14, decimal_places=2)


class Customer(models.Model):
    customer_id = ShortUUIDField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)


class CartItems(models.Model):
    cart_items_id = ShortUUIDField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    products = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (
            ("customer", "user", "products"),
        )

class Cart(models.Model):
    cart_id = ShortUUIDField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    cart_items = models.ManyToManyField(CartItems)
```

**serializers.py**

```
class CartSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = models.Cart
        fields = '__all__'
        read_only_fields = ['user']
```

I have tried to use all of the things below. Any help would be appreciated.
**Requirement:**
The cart_items must contain items of the selected customer only.

```
class CartSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """serializer for Product objects."""
    # authors = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Author.objects.all(), many=True)

    # cart_items = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=models.CartItems.objects.filter(customer=self.context['request'].user), many=True)
    # cart_items = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=models.CartItems.objects.filter(user=2), many=True)
    # cart_items = CustomerFilteredPrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, source='user.Customer')

    # cart_items = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField('get_cart')
    #
    # def get_cart(self, product):
    #     qs = models.CartItems.objects.filter(user=2)
    #     serializer = CartItemSerializer(instance=qs, many=True)
    #     return serializer.data

    class Meta:
        model = models.Cart
        fields = '__all__'
        read_only_fields = ['user']
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
class Cart(models.Model):
    cart_id = ShortUUIDField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    cart_items = models.ManyToManyField(CartItems)
```

Cart models have three `user(FK), customer(FK), cart_items(M2M)` dependency, so this field also need to serialize.

##### serializer

```py
# user serializer
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'

# customer serializer
class CustomerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = '__all__'


# cart-items serializer
class CartItemsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    customer = CustomerSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    product = ProductSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = CartItems
        fields = '__all__'
```

Now, serialize Cart model

```py
class CartSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    customer = CustomerSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    cart_items = CartItemsSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Cart
        fields = '__all__'
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you have only one `ForeignKey` from `CartItem` and `Cart` model to django's `User` model. Two ForeignKeys (one to `User`, and another to `Customer` seems redundant). And in the view class, override the `get_queryset` to filter the querset on the user sending the request. If you're gonna keep customer as a field on the Cart model, fetch the customer object using the user object from request.

```
# views.py
class CartView(GenericAPIView, ListModelMixin):
    ... # Don't pass queryset attr here
    
    serializer_class = CartSerializer
    
    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user
        queryset = Cart.objects.prefetch_related('cart_items').filter(user=user)
        # If you aren't changing your model, you could get the customer as:
        # customer = Customer.objects.get(user=user)
        # queryset = Cart.objects.prefetch_related('cart_items').filter(customer=customer) 
        return queryset
```

EDIT:
If what I understand is right, where you want to filter the queryset based on the customer, but the user in request is the merchant. I assume a `query_param` for the customer's id is being sent to the APIView, to filter the items.

try using this in get_queryset():

```
def get_queryset(self):
    customer_id = self.request.query_params.get('customer_id')
    # You could include the merchant user in the filter too, but I guess the customer filter would already narrow it down.
    queryset = Cart.objects.prefetch_related('cart_items__customer').filter(cart_items__customer_id=customer_id)
    return queryset
```

Comment: I require two Foreign keys because the user, in this case, is a merchant and the customer is the one allowed to add products(the user who has added this customer) to the cart. In this project, we will have multiple merchants(users) with their own products. The customers added by this merchant(user) is a customer only to this merchant and must only be able to his products to cart. But the manytomany field gives a list of all the products(of other merchants too) which is not desired. Therefore we need to filter these manytomany cart items based on selected customer.

Comment: We will not be able to get customer object by `customer = Customer.objects.get(user=user)` because every user will contain multiple customers. **ERROR:** `MultipleObjectsReturned: get() returned more than one Customer -- it returned 2!` Any suggestions?

Comment: Updated the answer. I'm assuming you're sending `customer_id` as a query_param to the view class.